# How can we get name of email templates using API?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

How can we get name of email templates using API? Can anyone please guide?

Comment: Hi Aastha, welcome to the community. Can you please provide more information on your use case? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Which API. Come on, put bit more effort in your question

You just need to run queries? Email templates are metadata, can be queried in [`EmailTemplate`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailtemplate.htm) table.

`SELECT Id, DeveloperName,FolderName,Name,NamespacePrefix FROM EmailTemplate`

If you're using Metadata API (retrieving config, deploying classes etc) you [need to explicitly list them in the package.xml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailtemplate.htm). If you don't know the names - you can query like above or use listMetadata call. Example if you're using Ant migration tool: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_listmetadata.htm (it'll work per folder)